# Finding the cell value 2 columns away dynamically

Tags: vba

I wanted to find the cell value 2 columns away. For example, i have found the closest number at A20, the next value i wanted to find will be at C20. Since the closest number may not always fall on A20. How do i code to find the cell.Value 2 columns away dynamically?

The code below is for I find my closest number

```
ClosestTime2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wsInput4.Value, Range("A5:A805"), 1, False)
```

I did research about it but i found Range.Offset nut suitable for my case.

Comment: Based on your expertise you can use find (vba function)..And the syntax will be like this :
ClosestTime2.Value=sheet1.Range("A5:A805").find(what:= wsInput4.Value).offset(0,2).value

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know that i can add offset function at the back.

Comment: If you don't want to use offset then you can hold the found value to a range type variable and then use that range to find the row and column of that range and add 2 with column and get the value..

Comment: You can add it but if you use Vlookup then you can't as vlookup returns value not a range where find returns range that's why you can use offset..

Comment: i did think about finding the cell address when i got the closest value but when i did, it will be $A$20. With that, im also stuck on how do i use that with the offset function.

Comment: Did you try the find function?

Comment: i did researched on find function, however, find function only find the value in the specific range that are being declared. I dont think that will work for what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the search range ahead of time, you could use **Match** instead of **VLookup**. Match returns the relative position of the matching item in the range. You can calculate the row number by adding the row number of the first row of the search range - 1. In this case, since your search range starts on row 5, you would need to add (5 - 1) = 4 to the offset returned by Match to yield the row number.

```
Offset = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsInput4.Value, Range("A5:A805"), 0)
RowNum = Offset + 4
NextValue = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
```

Comment: I think you are missing something..Match function return relative position(in this case if the number is found on A5 then it will give 1 as output..So you need to add 4 not subtract..

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
'Use your sheet code name for below line.
With Sheet3
    Dim foundcel As Range
    'Use proper data in according to your need.
    Dim output As String
    'Use below line for your case
    'Set foundcel = .Range("A5:A20").Find(what:=wsInput4.Value)
    
    Set foundcel = .Range("A5:A20").Find(what:="Liza")
    If Not foundcel Is Nothing Then
        output = .Cells(foundcel.Row, foundcel.Column + 2).Value
        
        'In your case use below line
        'ClosestTime2.Value=.Cells(foundcel.Row, foundcel.Column + 2).Value
    Else
        Debug.Print "Data not match"
    End If
    Debug.Print output
End With
End Sub
```

Data in sheet

[image]

Run output :
[image]